# How to cast to Angular Model variables in httpClient/Observable/Map or whatever?

Tags: angular, typescript, casting, type-conversion, observable

because I'm prety new in Angular/Typescript I still have some fundamental questions, but couldn't find an appropriate answer. How can I receive or cast the right value types?

I have defined a simple model:

```
export class Message {
    ID:                 number;
    mode:               string;
    senderID:           number;
    receiverID:         number;
    marked:             boolean;
    subject:            string;
}
```

Now I'm getting data from the server, via a message.service like:

```
getMessages(): Observable<Message[]> {
    return this.restService.get('/message/list/' + this.owner)
}
```

and in my component I read the values, via:

```
this.messageService.getMessages().subscribe((messages:Message[]) => {
    this.objectlist = messages
}
```

What I need and also expected are the real data types of the message elements, but everything is of **String**. Why there are no **booleans** and **numbers**?

I also played with pipe() and map(), but I'm not able to make a type conversion.

What I'm doing wrong? I hope that somebody can give me a helping hand. Thx in advance.

Comment: make sure the server is returning the boolean values

Comment: the server is returning a JSON object string and all numbered values are strings by default... booleans are returned as "0" or "1"

Comment: u need to return numbers as numbers from the server

Comment: Why? Why can't I convert the values returned from the server inside a map() function as I did in JS before?

Comment: @LarsHagen : It is better if it comes properly from the server. But If you want to, you can definitely do a map and typecast. What issye are you getting when you map()?

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript is just a typing layer of javascript. So you cannot magically cast one value into the other just by defining the typings. You really have to hardcode the types. In your case:

```
getMessages(): Observable<Message[]> {
  return this.restService.get('/message/list/' + this.owner).pipe(
    map((messages) => messages.map((message) => ({
      ...new Message(), ...message, ...{
        ID: parseInt(message.ID),
        senderID: parseInt(message.senderID),
        receiverID: parseInt(message.receiverID),
        marked: message.marked === '1'
      }
    }))
  )
}
```

This makes sure the returned object is really an array of the Message class. You can also think about using special decorators, which makes sure that when you create the class you get the proper type:

```
export class Message {
    @IsNumber()
    ID:                 number;
    mode:               string;
    @IsNumber()
    senderID:           number;
    @IsNumber()
    receiverID:         number;
    @IsBoolean()
    marked:             boolean;
    subject:            string;
}
```

There are some third party libraries you can use for this, or just implement them yourself.

You can then change the above code to:

```
messages.map((message) => ({...new Message(), ...message))
```

Comment: Hi PierreDuc, thank your for the example. I was in mind that Typescript will ensure that the types are correct based on their definitions. I tried your example above. Do I have something to import before, because @IsNumber()  and @IsBoolean() doesn't seem to exist (TS2552: Cannot find name 'IsNumber'. Did you mean 'Number'?)

Comment: Yes, the decorators are made up by me, but you can create your own decorators, if you have a lot of data structures coming from your backend, this is a good way to make sure they are the right type. Like I mentioned there are also some third party libraries which provide these. Besides that, you tell TypeScript what certain type an object will have. If it comes from an API call, you have to make sure the API send the right format

Comment: I tried both of your examples it didn't worked. The type casting wont work. The decorators were called before the data were avalable and so the state was always undefined.

Comment: the decorators should transform the properties into `setter` and `getter` functions, where the `setter` transforms the input in the right type and stores it in a `_ID` property, and the getter gets it from the `_ID` property. The first example should work nevertheless.. If it doesn't, then it means your backend is not actually returning an array of objects.